# ViewPager and linear Layout

Tags: android

Think I have an activity with some layouts, I want to know is it possible to use layouts in activity for thats activity ViewPager items ?

is it possible ? if so , how ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use viewpager with fragment. See the sample code below. I think this will be helpful for you.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support13Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv13/app/FragmentPagerSupport.html

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `ViewPager`, where each page holds a `Fragment`. This [sample code](http://tamsler.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-viewpager-and-fragments.html) explains how it can be done.

If you want your application to support pre-Honeycomb devices, you'll want to use the `ViewPager` and `Fragment`s from the [Android Support Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html).

Comment: the problem is here I use api level 9 and after adding support 4 , there is no getFragmentManager() in activity ,

Comment: If you are using the `Fragment`s from the Android Support Package, you should change `extend Activity` to `extend FragmentActivity`, and change any calls to `getFragmentManager()` to `getSupportFragmentManager()` (as well as any calls to `getLoaderManager()` to `getSupportLoaderManager()`).

Comment: also I have two exist linear layout in my activity , I know that I can move them to different layout and use layoutinfilator but the problem is here I can not use change views by findviewid after adding , ...